# Application url locally could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, routes

I am trying to develop simple Registration form and login form. If a user forgot his/her password then he clicks on `Forgot Password` button and a forgot password page opens where he will provide his/her email address and a password reset link is send to his/her mail address.Then he/she will click on the reset password and he will redirected to `changePassword.aspx` page but i am stuck with here. When i click on reset password link i got the following error. Please find images in attachments
[image: This the error i got]

Here is the code for password reset

```
protected void SetPasswordResetEmail(string UserName, string ToEmail, string UniqueId)
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage("email@gmail.com", ToEmail);
        StringBuilder sbEmailBody = new StringBuilder();
        sbEmailBody.Append("Dear" + UserName + ",<br/><br/>");
        sbEmailBody.Append("Please click the following link to reset your password");
        sbEmailBody.Append("<br/>");         
        sbEmailBody.Append("http://localhost/BootstrapLogin/ChangePassword.aspx?uid=" + UniqueId);
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = sbEmailBody.ToString();
        message.Subject = "Reset Your Password";
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password");
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
```

Comment: And are you running a web application on your computer?  With that URL?

Comment: try `localhost:8080`

Comment: Why are you searching localhost on google? Did you just go to that site by manually typing the url?

Comment: Can you post the part of the page that redirects you reset password page?

Comment: No , Its the page when i click on reset link i then redirected and i am using my web application on local host..I am not searching local host in google

Answer (score 0):

`Project -> Project_name Properties... -> Web`

Here you can see/change IIS port binding.

So in your url there should be this port number. Something like: `http://localhost/55555/BootstrapLogin...`

Comment: Why we use a specific port number? How we know that this port number will be open?

Comment: I have never seen localhost url on IIS without port. As per documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.ASPX VS invokes port itself, which later can be changed. You can always use port with large number, just to be safe

Comment: I use the project specific port number from the properties 'http://localhost:20918' but now when i click on reset link i landed on changepassword page with no resource found message... i am sure that i don't make mistake in the name of the page i-e ChangePassword.aspx. I am wonder where did i mistake

Answer (score 0):

option 1

```
sbEmailBody.Append("http://localhost/BootstrapLogin/ChangePassword.aspx?uid=" + UniqueId);
// http://localhost:8080 change 8080 to your application port number
```

option 2

Go to your project-> properties -> Web -> Server

Then give specific port number